# RTC Contributing Link Type - shows in web UI but not eclipse client

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rtc

I have contributed a link type to RTC using a plugin. The new link type now shows when I'm in the Web version on RTC but is unknown to the client. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also ship the plugin that declares the link type in a Eclipse client-side plugin, and that must be installed on the viewing user's Eclipse instance.